# How to load a page dynamically depending upon some flag using jquerymobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my index page there are many pages like

```
data-role="page1"
date-role="page2"
date-role="page3"
```

Now i need to show any of this page as soon as i open the index page... How to control this change just before the page is shown?

I tried to bind the pagebeforeshow on page1 like this

```
$("#page1").live("pagebeforeshow", function(e) {
    flag = window.location.search.substr(1);
    if(flag=='something') {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
    }
});
```

Although it moves to page2 but i am able to see this transition happening in front of my eyes on Android Browser.. How to do this in background?

Comment: let the index page load, then do it. try binding it on pageshow

Comment: @ghostCoder As the index.html will load.. it will load the page1... So u saying that i should bind it on pageshow of page1... M i right?

Comment: @ghostCoder Ok buddy Will let u know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this instead

```
$.mobile.changePage('#page2', {transition:'none'});
```

Also binding to pageinit works.

Comment: Hey i got it working...:)... Can you tell me the difference between $.mobile.changePage('#page2', {transition:'none'}); & $.mobile.changePage("#page2"); to clear me out....

Comment: Its just an option to specify what transition you want to use. In that case is specified that I didn't want a transition. If you don't specify it will use JQM's default transition.